# Photoshop: copy transparent layer with preserving anchors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a layer in Photoshop which contains some foreground graphics:

[image]

I want to copy this layer to another document (which contains the background: exactly same size, solid color):

[image]

How can I paste the foreground onto background to preserve its position?

Now, if I copy paste, my anchoring is rebased to the foreground color:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean "preserving the positioning". Anchors are something else entirely.  Use *Edit > Paste Special > Paste in Place* - or use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+V

Comment: Please consider posting this as answer, I'd be happy to accept it (Although it is a very easy problem, I couldn't find the answer in Google)

Comment: OK. I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "preserving the positioning". Anchors are something else entirely. Use *Edit > Paste Special > Paste in Place* - or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: One slight addition: pasting works, but can we somehow keep the positioning afterwards too?

Comment: @Daniel - What do you mean by "keep the position afterwards"?  After what?

Comment: After paste its position is only OK, if I paste it into the very same sized layer. If however I copy the background and paste it into a new bigger layer, then I cop the foreground and Paste in Place onto the new layer, how can I achieve to snap together the bg and fg on the new layer?

Comment: Perhaps you could select both layers (background and foreground) and click and drag them into your new composition. Then group the layers, then reposition as required. There's no way for the software to guess where you want to paste your content if the canvas is bigger. Computers can't read minds. They're just dumb machines. You need to tell them what to do. [see example](https://imgur.com/bWn1j7d)

Comment: Both layers are not presented in one document, but yeah, that was the solution: to have an intermediate document for merging these two, and then copy them as merged.

Comment: @Daniel - there's no need to merge the layers. That's destructive and usually not a good idea.

Comment: If I don't copy them merged, how else can you copy 2 layers onto a 3rd, larger doc? While preserving the 2 layers position?

Comment: @Daniel Select them both in the layers panel, and click and drag the layers into the other document. You can't preserve their position in the larger document, but it will preserve their position relative to each other. If positioning is a problem, make measurements, use guides etc.